# angular + ui-router + directive firing twice only if state is revisited

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

can anyone assist me with this bug?

When I navigate to a state that uses the directive,the link fires once.

When I leave to another state and revisit the same state and the link fires twice.

I've gone through the typical troubleshooting steps.  IE, closing directive elements, ng-if/ng-show, etc.

The directive doesn't use `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

angular 1.5.0, ui-router 0.2.18

thanks in advance.

my route config:

```
.state('map', {
            url: '/map/:searchId/{showSearch:bool}/:enableWizard',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/map/map.html',
            controller: 'mapController',
            controllerAs: 'mapCtrl',
            resolve: {
                'google-map': (uiGmapGoogleMapApi: any) => {
                    return uiGmapGoogleMapApi;
                }
            },
            params: {
                locateOnInit: null,
                searchId: null,
                showSearch: null,
                callback: null
            },
            data: {
                backButton: false
            }
        })
```

Comment: You say `directive` but there are none in your code sample. Only a `state` and `controller` are referenced. Also, you say the link fires twice. What is firing? and how do you know it was twice? This question needs more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning a controller to your state in your config and using ng-controller in your html code too. That may be the reason for the link firing twice .Remove ng-controller in your html . Try this and if it doesn't work please provide a fiddle or codepen

Comment: thanks for the reply.  my app is using `<html ng-app="myHomeSearch">` and my config is `.state('map', {
    url: '/map/:searchId/{showSearch:bool}/:enableWizard',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/map/map.html',
    controller: 'mapController',
    controllerAs: 'mapCtrl',
    resolve: {
     'google-map': (uiGmapGoogleMapApi: any) => {
      return uiGmapGoogleMapApi;
     }
    },
    params: {
     locateOnInit: null,
     searchId: null,
     showSearch: null,
     callback: null
    },
    data: {
     backButton: false
    }
   })` i might have to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: unfortunately, its not.  ive gone through all the basic ui-router troubleshooting to no avail.  still grasping straws.

Comment: it seems you are using controller in state config , so remove ng-controller from the ng-view

Comment: my app contains only one ng-view.  `<div    layout="column"
                layout-fill=''
                flex=''
                ui-view=''>

        </div>` and no `ng-controller`'s.

Comment: you mentioned in your question you are using ng-controller once , try removing that :)

Comment: i would really need to look at a fiddle or codepen to see the issue , because its not clear about what is firing twice and which directive